# Increasing speed for R recoding task

Tags: r, python-2.7

This question has multiple steps so bear with me.

**Premise**
The script I have created recodes a spreadsheet with 43000 columns, each a unique variable with 177 observations. The observations are all different and are decimal numbers.

Each individual variable is then recoded into two groups; based on a cutoff point. This cutoff point has been generated from a previous script I've written.  There is one cutoff point associated with EACH variable/column - so the cutoff's are unique and is sourced from a list of 43000 cutoff numbers. Based on this, numbers within the column are subsequently recoded into two groups; either 1 or 0 - depending on whether they are > or <. See example below:

How I've done it so far is to use the R plyr package for example:

```
Genedata$SPOCK1.202363_at_recode[Genedata$SPOCK1.202363_at<= 8.2244399999999995] <- "0"
Genedata$SPOCK1.202363_at_recode[Genedata$SPOCK1.202363_at> 8.2244399999999995] <- "1"
Genedata_Recoded$SPOCK1.202363_at_recode <- factor(Genedata$SPOCK1.202363_at_recode)
```

In this instance the variable is : `SPOCK1.202363_at` and the cutoff is 8.2244399999999995

However, given that both the variable name and the cutoff change with each individual variable, I am not aware how to use the `apply` function in R.

As a result I am currently using PyPer a Python module that can call R functions. Using the placeholder `%s`, I iteratively replace each variable name and cutoff value.

**Problems**

1) Currently opening the CSV file takes a long time --> I think saving as a binary file or matrix will speed this up. However this is NOT priority.

2) Iterating; is there a way to use apply function with two changing variables using the recode function using the plyr package.

3) The current time taken to iterate seems to increase non linearly with variables. For 1000 variables it takes about 30 seconds, but for 43000 it seems to slow down. I don't know the cause of this. Perhaps an explanation?

4) Is there a way to easily parallelize iterative tasks using the multiprocessing packageso that speed is further increased

**Update:** In response to why "0" and "1" it doesn't matter if numeric or non-numeric. I just chose that. Ultimately the next part of my analysis takes two groups regardless if numeric or not and processes it.

**Update 2:** Rephrased the premise to be more clear

Comment: for starters you can use `var_recoded <- factor((var_to_recode > mean(var_to_recode)) * 1)` instead of your three-liner

Comment: For big data use `data.table`, every time you use `a$b <- c` you will copy `a`

Comment: In one call, `t(1*(t(data) > means)` will give you a matrix of 0 and 1. It should be fast too. `means` might be `colMeans(data)` but it is not clear from your description.

Comment: It looks like you are getting a lot of helpful answers, but none as actual _answers_.  Perhaps consider editing this multi part question down to a single question, then asking subsequent questions as needed.

Comment: Can you update your question with an explanation of why you want it to be "0" and "1", rather than the numeric 0 and 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Idea # 1: Why not:

```
Genedata$SPOCK1.202363_at_recode <- factor( Genedata$SPOCK1.202363_at <= 8.2244399999999995, 
                                      labels=c("0", "1") )
```

That way you don't need to process the inequality twice. You could skip the `factor` call if you could accept it as a logical vector:

```
Genedata$SPOCK1.202363_at_recode <-  Genedata$SPOCK1.202363_at <= 8.2244399999999995
```

Idea #2: This would surely be faster for multiple rows for a matrix named "X":

```
X <- (X < rep( colMeans(X), each=nrow(X) ) )
```

You could do it like this:

```
Genedata[ , cols_to_process] <- ( Genedata[ , cols_to_process] < 
                                  rep( cutoff_vector, 
                                         each=nrow(Genedata[ , cols_to_process]) ) )
```

Notice that this is essentially what @flodel's comment was suggesting, because he was converting columns to rows and depending on argument recycling, and then restoring the original structure. Regarding the parallelization option, I don't think this fairly small dataset warrants the effort. This took about 3 minutes on a 5  year-old machine:

```
 dfrm <- data.frame(matrix(rnorm(43000*170), 170) )
 cutoff <- rnorm(43000, 0, 0.2)
 system.time( dfrm[ , 1:43000] <- ( dfrm[ , 1:43000] < 
                                   rep( cutoff, 
                                          each=170 ) ) )
#   user  system elapsed 
#129.052  57.449 185.660
```

Converting to a matrix might speed this up considerably:

```
 mtx <- matrix(rnorm(43000*170), 170) 
 system.time( mtx <- t(1*(t(mtx) > cutoff) )  )
 #  user  system elapsed 
 # 0.226   0.133   0.358 
 mtx <- matrix(rnorm(43000*170), 170)
 system.time( mtx[ , 1:43000] <- ( mtx[ , 1:43000] < 
                                   rep( cutoff, 
                                          each=170 ) ) )
 #  user  system elapsed 
 # 0.852   0.001   0.849 
 #Now do it all at once............
 system.time( mtx <- mtx < rep( cutoff, each=170 ) ) 
  # user  system elapsed 
  #0.095   0.000   0.094
```

Comment: I've changed from the three lines to the one. It makes the code more elegant, but doesn't seem to affect performance significantly. I took the labels instead of logical vector, because it is easier for the next step of my script. 

As for the matrix; I might use the data.table as someone suggested; it seems more straightforward and the performance gain is good.

I'm not sure about the last bit of the code you suggested. The cutoff point by which i'm dichotimizing my data changes with each column. Its not just replicating.

Comment: Yes, and the "cutoff point" will change with every column. That's what the rep() call is doing.

Comment: OK, looking into it, cheers.  :) Quick question. Will this work with data.table? And thoughts on data.table vs matrix?

Comment: The code is short and works perfectly for what its meant to do; but I made an original mistake in my wording of my question which I corrected. The Cutoff is not the mean but rather a value calculated using the R maxstat package. Still this is very useful for another script i'm writing. so cheers.

Comment: It doesn't really matter how you create the test vector. Substitute your (unspecified) cutoff vector for the colMeans() call and proceed along.

Comment: Makes sense now, I just don't know R very well. Thanks a lot again!